# How to acces view properties from coroutines result

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am trying to do simple request to backend with coroutines

```
    uiScope.launch {
        try {
             result = URL("https://httpbin.org/get").readText()
            text.text = result
        } catch (error: Error) {
            text.text = error.message
        } finally {
                log(this@MainActivity,result)

        }
    }
```

but this exeption is thrown:

> `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I can not access UI component from another thread, at the same time I can not make internet request on the main thread. So I should chouse one of them. Solution was to use ViewModel components and update it's LiveDate value which subsequently will chane the UI

```
    var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.selected.observe(this, Observer{ users ->

        text.text = users
    })
    uiScope.launch {
            try {
                result = URL("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").readText()
                viewModel.selected.postValue(result)
            } catch (error: Error) {
                viewModel.selected.postValue(error.toString())
            }

    }
    log(this@MainActivity,result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `uiScope` isn't set up correctly, apparently its dispatcher is not `Dispatchers.Main`. So the first thing to fix is your implementation of the `coroutineContext` property, which should be

```
override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()
```

Once you fix that, your code will be making a blocking call on the UI thread. To make the blocking call on a background thread, but still keep the rest of the coroutine on the UI thread, write

```
uiScope.launch {
    try {
         text.text = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             URL("https://httpbin.org/get").readText()
         }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        text.text = e.message
    } finally {
        log(this@MainActivity, result)
    }
}
```

Comment: again   "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."  thrown

Comment: This indicates that you didn't set up `uiScope` to actually be a UI-based coroutine scope. Its `coroutineContext` must return `Dispatchers.Main + job`.

Comment: but Dispatchers.Main throws:  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException